# NativeScript Angular Changing .ns-root variable dynamically

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have the following app.css with the css variable "--primary-color". Is is possible to change this variable in any component file or service?

app.css

```
.ns-root {
    --primary-color: white;
}

.page {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

For example, in angular for web, i can change this variable with 
"*document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary-color', 'black');*" but not in nativescript angular.

Comment: You can not change the variable like you would in web, but a workaround could be using the [addCss](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#addcss) method, inject updated CSS as string dynamically into your root element.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, will try out this method and see whether it works

Comment: @Manoj is there any way to use addCss to inject new style into global css (app.css)? I tried to use addCss in app.component but it only update style in the first page.

Comment: Nvm, i got it. We need to add it to application instead of page